# Largest integer which cannot be made with 5x + 7y where x and y are integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the largest positive integer $n_0$ for which there are no $x, y ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ with $x, y ≥ 0$ so that $n_0 = 5x + 7y$?

Give a proof that if $n > n_0$ then there are non-negative integers $x$ and $y$ so that $n = 5x + 7y$.

Comment: No, he stated it correctly. (The smallest is trivially $1$.)

Comment: From some point onwards, every integer is representable as $5x+7y$, so it does make sense to ask for the largest which cannot be so represented.

Comment: The largest integer not possible is $(5-1)(7-1)-1=23$. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118907/guess-the-number-of-red-balls/2118923#2118923

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Largest integer that can't be represented as a non-negative linear combination of $m, n = mn - m - n$? Why?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66963/largest-integer-that-cant-be-represented-as-a-non-negative-linear-combination-o)

Comment: @OldJohn.  But the *small* integers can *not* be represented.  1,2,3,4 are impossible as they are all less than 5.  6, 8,9, 11 are impossible.  This isn't a "how far can I go before something stops" question.  This is a "how far do I have to go before something *starts*" question.

Comment: Oops.  I misread old johns comment.  He basically said the same thing I did.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a formula if the least common divisor of the 2 numbers (5, 7) is equal to 1, which is always true for primes:
$$g(a,b)=(a-1)(b-1)-1,gcd(a,b)=1$$
$$g(5,7)=(5-1)(7-1)-1=23$$

Comment: My bad, gonna fix it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). For given $c_1,c_2$ with $\gcd(c_1,c_2)=1$, the largest number which *cannot* be represented by $ac_1+bc_2$ with $a,b \ge 0$ is $(c_1c_2-c_1-c_2)$.

The intuition I prefer to understand this is to see what the value of multiples of the larger coin, say $c_1$, is modulo the smaller $c_2$, and see that the last modular equivalence is filled at $c_1c_2-c_1$, which means it must still be open at $(c_1c_2-c_1-c_2)$

Comment: By now this Q must be a duplicate of a duplicate of a ......